# Good testing requires lots of classes, when does the this degrade performance?

Tags: unit-testing, architecture, coding-style

For good unit testing you should have allot of classes.

This will mean that you have allot of test classes but shouldn't actually have to spend more time maintaining them as they will be simpler and fewer of them will be hit per change compared to a smaller number of classes with more functionality per class.

Is there any real performance hit to an application running that has allot of classes (probably with DI) compared to one with fewer, fatter classes?

**EDIT**

Let me clarify.

I'm not talking about the algorithms, I was wondering on, in general, if allot of classes was ever a performance hit.

Do you think that allot of classes, I'm thinking of one public method per class and almost all private methods extracted to classes.

This is very extreme, but hypothetically, what would the problem be?

Comment: Supporting fat classes has developer performance hit which cannot be solved by upgrading system. Also you should profile your application to see if classes creation has any significant impact on system performance

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You're asking if there is ever a performance hit.  That's just plain the wrong question.  There is *always* a performance hit, it's just negligible in context, and even when it's not, performance is *almost* always cheaper to solve using hardware rather than software, even now that clock speeds have plateaued.  In those few cases where it is not cheaper to buy faster silicon, classes are not going to be your limiting factor, and the rest of this answer applies.

In my experience, most things that need performance enhancements are bound by things other than unit granularity. Using a faster data storage mechanism or index on your data, or a better in-memory collection architecture, or using a dictionary and loop instead of a nested loop, all make large jumps in performance possible.  Once you have these taken care of, if you are still concerned about performance, you are left with a small number of options, most of which require very careful hand-optimization of code in an extremely performant language, which typically means getting someone who is a top-tier coder to do the core of an algorithm.

There is also the simple principle to remember: Beware Premature Optimization.

Answer (score 2):

What feel right now is called "[premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)": The fear/urge to fix a problem that might never ever happen.

Loading classes in general isn't slow because all the related code has been optimized to death since everyone uses it.

Also if class loading takes a few seconds per test run (= the whole run, *not* per test), that doesn't matter since your tests usually run much longer (many orders of magnitude more if you do it wrong).

That leaves the last and worst problem: Maintenance. Each line of code written is one that needs to be *at least* ignored when you maintain the code. Even ignoring code takes effort. So less code is always better.

But there is a lower limit here; you just need a minimum amount of code to encode all the features you need. Also, trying to reach the absolute minimum for the required features takes a lot of effort, so most code only gets (somewhat) close.

Unfortunately, that still isn't the whole picture: If you have well written code, then you won't have to look at it - it will just work. So the maintenance cost of well written code is much lower than, say, compact, fast but incomprehensible code.

That means that code is cheaper when it's easy to understand. Which means splitting it up into independent bits will make it cheaper. That will, because of the flaws of [OOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Criticism), lead to a class explosion.

Unfortunately, our brainpower is limited. This means if a feature is spread over too many places, it will be harder to grasp the whole picture. This gets worse when the code isn't cut in exactly the right place (and it most often isn't) plus the fact that no one can writer perfect code over a long period of time (so the quality changes).

Conclusion: You can have too many or too few classes. There is no way to tell from the outside. It depends on how good you/your team are, how complex your problem is, how big the project is, etc. A good indicator is the number of open bugs in your bug database and experience.

Comment: That's basically what I was thinking.  I was pondering what metrics I might be able to collect to measure it.

Comment: Take 1'000 successful projects and measure the number of classes, methods per class, length of methods. If you get a Gauss distribution for the numbers, there is probably a correlation between these numbers and code quality.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any real performance hit to an application running that has allot of classes (probably with DI) compared to one with fewer, fatter classes?

High performance comes from implementing efficient algorithms. Efficient algorithms are often harder to code, and thus require better testing. Using many classes to ensure good testing makes it easier to code efficient algorithms, and thus provides better performance.